# Is it possible to sort the Firebase data and apply it to the Real Time DB on Android Studio?

Tags: android, sorting, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to sort my Firebase DB data on the Android Studio side and apply it in real-time. My codes successfully updates the view immediately when I make a manual change on my DB, but I wonder if I can sort by name using the code. I thought orderByChild was the function to do that, but it does not change the database.

**Function that fetches data from firebase and displays:**

```
private void fetchRepoData(String profileUserID) {

    profileUserDatabase = repoReference.child(profileUserID);

    //DatabaseReference reposReference = profileUserDatabase.child("Repos");

    profileUserDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            repoListItems.clear();
            repoNameList.clear();
            userNameList.clear();
            descriptionList.clear();

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                repoNameList.add(snapshot.getValue(RepoInfo.class).getRepoName());
                userNameList.add(snapshot.getValue(RepoInfo.class).getOwner());
                descriptionList.add(snapshot.getValue(RepoInfo.class).getDescription());
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < repoNameList.size(); i++) {
                repoListItems.add(new RepositoryItem(i, repoNameList.get(i), userNameList.get(i), descriptionList.get(i)));
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

**Radio button for sorting by name**

```
    sortByNameRadio.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    repoReference.child("subchild").orderByChild("name");
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `orderByChild()` it returns a **new `Query` object**. You'll need to store a reference and attach a listener *that* query object.

```
profileUserDatabase = repoReference.child(profileUserID);

Query query = repoReference.child("subchild").orderByChild("name");

query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        System.out.println(snapshot.getKey());
        ...
```

Comment: Is there anything that I have to do inside the query.addValueEventListener?

Comment: I added a line that prints the keys of the child nodes. Aside from that, it's hard to say what else is needed.